# Routes with permisssion set to isAuthenticated cannot be accessed from thunder client(or postman)

Tags: api, visual-studio-code, django-rest-framework

I am building API in django rest framework and i test these APIs from a vs code extension called **thunder client** which works similarly as **postman**.

I am using `django-rest-knox` for token authentication and added it to the settings also;

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',)
}
```

Then in the views.py;

```
from rest_framework import permissions
permission_classes = [
    permissions.IsAuthenticated
]
```

But in Thunder client as well as in postman, if we want to access a route which requires permissions, that just returns `authentication credentials were not provided` even after providing the credentials (in my case, it is a token).

The API works fine in the frontend but in thunder client and postman, it behaves that way.

Comment: kindly show how you are setting up the request in thunder client

Comment: As we do. Provide the url, set the method and also provide the Authorization header. That is working fine from frontend and i think the way i am sending the request has no problems but maybe thunder client has some restrictions.

Comment: I am using axios on frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because i found the solution and that was a little non-sense for me.

As tokens are long strings, so every one prefers to copy paste them. So did i.

And we need to set a header `Authorization` in the request to validate a user;

```
Authorization: Token <token>
```

As there is a space b/w `Token` and the value of the token `<token>`. I used to put that fist and then paste the token value. But when i removed that space and added it after pasting the token value, it worked.

Still don't know why??